# Kicking after ACL Reconstruction

Tags: muay-thai, knees

I was wondering if anyone who has gone through an ACL recon, specifically with an allograft, could say when they started moving freely again. By moving freely, I mean kicking with both legs and shadow boxing/pivoting on the operation leg without any reservations. Note, I mean just movement and shadow boxing/kicking...not sparring, or any contact work. Similar to what Conor Mcgregor is doing in this video, maybe excluding all the level changes and fancy jump kicks where both feet leave the mat

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5_qFzz730No

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through ACL recon in 2015 November, was pretty lazy in rehab and ended with a weak hamstring. I have always been told and recommended that kicks with the knee that was repaired generally will take longer to feel natural again, especially in relation to pivoting on the operational leg. I was able to do roundhouses after 7 months and pivoting on the operational leg after 11 months.

I have been able to pivot on operation leg and do the demonstration above for about 2 months now. If you have done correct rehabilitation for being able to pivot on the operation leg and have full range of motion you should be able to commence when you feel you can complete all the motions required without feeling pain - It largely varies from person to person. If I am correct I do believe Conor McGregor returned to practice within 4 months of injury to his ACL in the fight vs Holloway.

If this time period is way too long maybe you should look into doing light work and no pivots after 4 months.

http://sportsmetrics.org/published-rates-of-reinjury-after-acl-reconstruction-show-need-for-advanced-neuromuscular-retraining/

http://lermagazine.com/article/rehab-speeds-return-after-acl-surgery

Comment: Did you get an allograft? And to confirm, you were kicking with your non operational leg (i.e. pivoting with your operational leg) at 7 or 11 months?

Comment: I luckily had a hamstring graft. It makes to note that allografts are not the same as they are donated, but it will be fine. Studies show that Allografts may impede you but after time (5 years) there is no difference rather than a change in range of motion. I was pivoting on the operation leg after 11 months because I'm not a super athlete or anything, I was doing standard Muay Thai teeps and roundhouses 7 months after. http://www.arthroscopyjournal.org/article/S0749-8063(01)52643-2/abstract?cc=y=

Comment: Could you summarise the content of the two links you provided. Links only are subject to rot and thus not really useful. Thanks.